# Button Toggle using :before :after with Font Awesome Icons

Tags: jquery, css, button, font-awesome, pseudo-class

I have a toggle button that uses the bars Font Awesome icon and I'm using the :after pseudo class to add a left caret to the left side of the bars. When I click the button, I want the left caret to go away and a right caret on the right side of the bars to appear. An example of this functionality is seen on the [One Codex Beta Site](https://beta.onecodex.com/) (on that site it starts with a right caret on the right side of the bars, whereas I'm starting with a left caret on the left side of the bars).

I've Googled for help on how to do this, but I haven't been able to get this to work as I want it to. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you!

HTML

```
<div id="header" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div id="logo" class="navbar-brand">
                    <button type="button" id="toggleSidebar">
                        <i class="navbar-icon fa fa-bars icon"></i>
                    </button><a href="index2.html" class="brand noline" title="Home">Brand</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="nav-join"><a href="#" id="join" title="Join">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li id="nav-signin"><a href="#" id="sign-in" title="Sign In">Sign In</a></li>
                    <li id="nav-about-us"><a href="#" id="about-us" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.asm = {};
            $.asm.panels = 2;

            $('#toggleSidebar').click(function(){
                if ($.asm.panels === 1) {
                    $('#content').attr({'class': 'products col-lg-9'});
                    $('#sidebar').show();
                    $.asm.panels = 2;
                } else {
                    $('#content').attr({'class': 'col-lg-12'});
                    $('#sidebar').hide();
                    $.asm.panels = 1;
                }
            });
        });
```

CSS

```
.fa-bars:after {
  content: "\f0d9";
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#content {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msmasiello/jt7pao19/)

Comment: I don't see anything like this on the One Codex site.

Comment: Look at the top left corner where the sidebar toggle button is. See how the caret switches on click?

Comment: There's nothing there for me. Of course, I'm not logged in. Maybe you're looking at a logged in version of the site.

Comment: Ah you're right. I hadn't realized I was logged in. Apologies for including such a poor example, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a class to rewrite the content for the icon, i.e:

JS

```
$('#toggleSidebar').click(function(){
$(this).find('.navbar-icon').toggleClass('right');
```

CSS

```
.fa-bars.right::after {
content: "";
float: right;
padding-left: 5px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5xtmapqp/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is going on in your fiddle with how you initially set .fa-bars, but I would add/takeaway CSS classes in the jQuery logic.  I've rewritten your #toggleSidebar.change function:

```
$('#toggleSidebar').click(function(){
            if ($.asm.panels === 1) {
                $('#content').attr({'class': 'products col-lg-9'});
                $('#sidebar').show();
                $('.fa-bars').removeClass('i-right-caret').addClass('i-left-caret');
                $.asm.panels = 2;
            } else {
                $('#content').attr({'class': 'col-lg-12'});
                $('#sidebar').hide();
                $('.fa-bars').removeClass('i-left-caret').addClass('i-right-caret');
                $.asm.panels = 1;
            }
        });
```

Where "i-right-caret" and "i-left-caret" are the font-awesome classes that determine the carets (I think there is usually an 'fa' in there?  I'm not sure).

Comment: I'll try this out and see if it works. So basically I shouldn't even use the :after pseudo class to do this?

Comment: I only use the :after and :before pseudo classes if I'm dealing with a navigation menu, or something very simple involving divs.  They are confusing and I can't control when they are given their status, so I would much rather use jQuery - where I can see exactly when something is happening.

Comment: Gotcha. So the problem I'm having when I implement your solution is that fa-bars just gets replaced by the left/right caret; the carets aren't being "added" next to the bars.

Comment: I would just modify the .addClass to include "fa-bars" as well, like addClass('i-right-caret fa-bars')